# Unable to run 'tcl' file on Vivado 2016.4 version

Tags: memory, tcl, vivado

I am trying to run a .tcl file originally configured for 2014.4 on 2016.4 version of Vivado. However I am getting the following error:

```
    while executing
"create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:mig mig_0 "
    (procedure "create_root_design" line 111)
    invoked from within
"create_root_design """
    (file "all.tcl" line 405)
```

The tcl file uses the part 'xcku040-ffva1156-2' and tries to access the IP 'mig' which I believe is renamed/changed on later versions. Is there any workaround for this?

Steps I have done till now:

1. Changed the version number to 2016.4
2. tried replacing target boards.
3. tried on the same board with an alternate IP for mig.
4. tried on both 2016.4 and 2015.4 versions

None of these have worked so far

Attaching the '.tcl' file for reference : [all.tcl](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/665714/all.tcl)

Comment: That's odd; you've got the stack trace but not the actual error message part. Could the error message (out of `create_bd_cell`) be empty? Tcl itself doesn't generate empty error messages if possible, as they're incredibly confusing, but `create_bd_cell` isn't Tcl so much as (presumably) Vivado…

Comment: Yeah I contacted Xilinx support for Vivado regarding this. Seems like they have discontinued/renamed mig (Memory Interface Generator) on newer versions. So you have to run this script on 2014 version, generate the design and then open the same design using 2015 version. The 2015 version will automatically suggest upgrades to the discontinued/renamed IPs. Repeat the same to get to 2016 version. That's the only way to get this done. Also have to keep checking if the core functionality of the IP is the same after automated upgrades by Vivado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since with every version upgrade of the Vivado Design Suite, parts are renamed or removed, it is not possible to run a .tcl file meant for an earlier version in newer releases. So I ran the above query on Xilinx Community Forums and found a workaround:

Run this script on the previous version(2014 in this case), generate the design and then open the same design using the next major release(2015 version). The 2015 version will automatically suggest upgrades to the discontinued/renamed IPs. Repeat the same to get to 2016 version. That's the only way to get this done. Also have to keep checking if the core functionality of the IP is the same after automated upgrades by Vivado Design Suite.